# How to call an external program (.exe) after modal solution in Ansys MAPDL script

Tags: matlab, ansys-apdl

I'm trying to call a .exe file (Matlab routine) after a modal solution in an Ansys MAPDL script. Is there an APDL command for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) and call any .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Mechanical APDL help on the /SYS and /SYP commands.  /SYS allows us to pass a command string to the OS for execution.  Normally I've only used this to do simple things like copy a file, or get a listing of files (for troubleshooting).  I don't have access to Matlab.  I did test sending:

/sys, python a.py

From MAPDL interactive where a.py was just print hello then quit.  And that worked.